# None type object has no attribute error in webcrawler Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to Python so any help would be appreciated. I have a web crawler using beautifulsoup. It works but for the below it returns the error 'None type object has no attribute'. I know it means it has come across a page where there is no entry.
How do I stop this error and make it return all the other pages that have entries. Some of the pages in the web crawler have the entry and some are blank.

```
bbb = re.compile('First listed')
    next_s = soup.find(text=bbb).parent.parent.get_text(strip=True)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
bbb = re.compile('First listed')
next_s = soup.find(text=bbb)
if next_s is not None:
    # node exists
else:
    # node does not exists
```

Comment: thanks what do i put under the 'if next_s is not None:'?

Comment: depends on the logic of your script. if you have a list of links, and iterate over it in `for` loop then use `continue`, for next iteration.

Comment: I'm pretty new to coding so i'm not too sure what that means. 
It doesnt have many links in the crawler, most of my code is below: where would I put the for and continue statements?
Def get_single_item_data(item_url): 
    source_code = requests.get(item_url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
bbb = re.compile('First listed')
next_s = soup.find(text=bbb)
writer.writerow([address, price, Bedroom, Description, Sold, next_s, next_ss])

Comment: can you post the example of HTML for parsing?

Comment: The below is the beginning of the code: I posted the rest of the code above. Thanks for your help.

url = 'http://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/property/manchester/?page_size=100&q=Manchester%2C%20Greater%20Manchester&radius=0&results_sort=newest_listings&search_source=refine'

        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
        for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'listing-results-price text-price'}):
            href = "http://www.zoopla.co.uk" + link.get('href')
get_single_item_data(href)

Comment: ok, as I understand it, the function `get_single_item_data()` parses one page and write a result to CSV file. But some pages do not contain the data you need. Logic is `if page contains data -> extract it and write to file, otherwise -> do nothing` or in python `next_s = soup.find(text=bbb); if next_s is not None: writer.writerow(<extracted data here>);`

Comment: thanks. I have various items I pull out not just next_s e.g
     cc = re.compile('First listed')
     next_ss = soup.find(text=ccc).parent.parent.parent.get_text(strip=True)
     How do I write this on the writer.writerow line for both to contain not none items only, thanks